# Need some agent to index/search remote file for Remote development

Tags: phpstorm, sftp, remote-server

I have pretty heavy project to run locally on my notebook, and it runs on my local server machine. But i want to work with it from my notebook, locally without any screen sharing tool. I've tried to establish sftp connection with server and opened the project with PhpStorm, but it's terrifically slow..

Must say, that loading the files, saving, debugging - rather fast, but search and indexing (MOSTLY INDEXING) very slow. Maybe, is there any phpstorm agent for remote servers, that indexes on host, and sends via network summary data to my local PhpStorm application?

Or, maybe another tool with such remote agent. Like Atom plugins, Sublime.. or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create 2 copies of source code the project.
One on your workstation, the second on your laptop.
After it, you can write a little script, which would watch your directory on the laptop and copy it to the workstation.

I use chokidar from npm (https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)

Code example:

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

chokidar.watch('repository', {ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../}).on('all', (event, path) => {
    if (event === 'change') {
        console.log(event, path);

        exec('scp "' + path + '" "${PATH_TO_WORKSTATION_PROJECT}' + path + '"', 
             function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err); 
             }
             console.log(stdout);
        });
    }
});
```

Also you would need to configure remote debugging (but it's another topic)

Answer (score 1):

There are no indexing agents for remote project accessing. It's recommended to work with locally stored project files with JetBrains IDEs.